# Postgres regexp_matches. How to find word after range of words

Tags: regex, postgresql

I want to parse query in postgres
I've got string query, for example `Select * FROM dm.lib Update sc.qar Join ws.gys`

How can I get first word after following pattern words - SELECT, UPDATE, JOIN?

I use this query and get many NULL values.

```
with src(txt) as (
  values ('Select * FROM dm.lib Update sc.qar Join ws.gys')
)
select unnest(regexp_matches (txt, 'FROM ([^ ]+) | SELECT ([^ ]+) | UPDATE ([^ ]+) | JOIN ([^ ]+) | DELETE ([^ ]+) | MERGE ([^ ]+)','g')) 
from src 
where ;
```

it is important that upper case of lower doesn't matter.
My query doesn't work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/3fde0tW6)
Probably over engineered. There should be a simple way, but the following is how I do.

```
WITH src (txt) AS (
    VALUES ('Select * FROM       dm.lib Update     sc.qar Join     ws.gys'))
,cte (keywords) AS (
    SELECT unnest('{FROM,select,UPDATE,JOIN,DELETE,MERGE}'::text[]))
,cte1 AS (
    SELECT
        regexp_instr (lower(txt), lower(keywords) || '\s+') AS BEGIN
    ,lower(keywords) || '\s+' AS pattern
    ,lower(keywords) AS keywords
    ,lower(txt) AS src
FROM    cte, src
)
,cte2 AS (
    SELECT
        *
        ,regexp_instr (src, pattern,BEGIN, 1, 1) AS pattern_end
        ,coalesce(lead(BEGIN) OVER (ORDER BY BEGIN),length(src) + 2) 
        - 1 
        - regexp_instr (src, pattern,BEGIN, 1,1) AS gap
FROM cte1 WHERE BEGIN != 0
ORDER BY 1
)
SELECT
    *, substring(src FROM pattern_end FOR gap)
FROM cte2;
```

src, cte, cte1 used to normalized strings.
Key function is **regexp_instr** (only in postgres 15: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

Key gotcha is that You can use regexp_instr get the match substring begin char position and end char position, It feel like char pointer walk through in C.

Comment: Wow, looks interesting. How can I use it in Postgres 11? Can you help?

Comment: https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=6424337073589476303b10f6d7cc74f501b8d9d7 the change is very limited. You can probably write a c function than You can use it in pg11. or install pg15 then use pg15 connect to pg11.